# jQuery anchor slide - not working in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scroll, anchor, slide

The navigation sliding no longer works on my company's site; http://www.adaptdesign.com when using Google Chrome. It used to work perfectly until I updated the browser...

The script was downloaded from http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/better-html-anchor-a-jquery-script-to-slide-the-scrollbar/ , I replaced my one with those again incase those were newer, and his example at www.position-relative.net/creation/anchor/ works in Chrome whereas my website still doesn't scroll (clicking the link has no effect at all)!

I'm stumped as to why this isn't working... does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Citizen, what version are you using?

Comment: 14.0.803.0 dev-m. I also tested on 13.0.782.32 beta and its working fine as well.

Comment: Interesting - my version is apparently up to date but is only 12.0.742.112?! Perhaps this will be work as it should in the next version of Chrome...?

Comment: That's because you're on the release channel and the two versions I sent you are both beta and dev channels... If I can find someone with the release version I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem with this script in Chrome. It appears it's caused by empty named anchors.

```
<a name="top" id="top"></a>
```

doesn't catch links, but

```
<a name="top" id="top">
<ul>
...
</ul>
</a>
```

does. Try wrapping your

```
<a name="aboutblock" id="aboutblock"></a>
```

around something.